# PreparedStatement: getIngredientByName

Tags: java, html, mysql, indexing, prepared-statement

How would I go about modifying this snippet of code for PreparedStatement? I've seen how to do this with a number variable, but I seem to be having some trouble with String variables...

```
@Path("/ingredients/name")
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getIngredientByName(@QueryParam("name") String theName) 
throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
 //Obtaining an ingredient from the database
 String connectStr="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fooddb";
 String username="root";
 String password="csci330pass";
 String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 Class.forName(driver);
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, username, password);
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, name, category FROM ingredient WHERE 
 name='" + theName + "'");

 String result = "";
 while (rs.next()) 
 {
  int theId3 = rs.getInt("id");
  String theName3 = rs.getString("name");
  String theCategory = rs.getString("category");
  result += "id: "+theId3+ " , name: "+theName3 + "("+theCategory+")" + "\n" + "\n";
 }
  return result;
 }//END METHOD
}//END CODE
```

Another concern I have is that this code might be missing something, due to how it returns only the first result whenever I try to enter in credentials that are not the same as those results. Again, this code corresponds to an index.html file I created recently...

Comment: "Where name=?" And the use setString(1, name)

Comment: While that is very helpful, what would the code exactly look like after taking your suggestion. I'm sorry to be asking this, but I'm concerned about where it should go so when compiling, errors that occur can be minimal and easily contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've seen how to do this with a number variable, but I seem to be having some trouble with String variables

It's exactly the same process but instead you use `setString`, as described in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) and [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

```
public String getIngredientByName(@QueryParam("name") String theName)
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //Obtaining an ingredient from the database
    String connectStr = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fooddb";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "csci330pass";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver);
    String result = "";
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, username, password)) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id, name, category FROM ingredient WHERE name =?")) {
            stmt.setString(1, theName);
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int theId3 = rs.getInt("id");
                    String theName3 = rs.getString("name");
                    String theCategory = rs.getString("category");
                    result += "id: " + theId3 + " , name: " + theName3 + "(" + theCategory + ")" + "\n" + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}//END METHOD
```

You're also not managing your resources, you need to make sure that once you have competed using the resources, that you close them, this would cause issues with the database if you're not careful

Take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thank you for the advice - this improves my situation greatly - both past and present...